# Python does not tell JSON from string

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a json file like this:

```
"[\"SOMEURL",\"SOMEURL",\"SOMEURL",\"SOMEURL"]"
```

and I need to put these values to the array

but such code as

```
fileObject = open("doc_1.json", "r")
jsonContent = fileObject.read()
aList = json.loads(jsonContent)
print(aList)
```

opens it as a simple string, so I can't take any element of the list above.
Any clues I found on internet fit only for JSON files with complex structure, with dictionaries and so on, but it's not the case. How do I read it?

Comment: This is because not all the double quotes (specifically the ending quotes) in that string are escaped. I'm, assuming they are supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

To read the JSON data you have into a Python list, you need to ensure that your JSON data is properly formatted. In your provided JSON data, it seems there are issues with the quotes and escape characters. Here's the corrected JSON data:

```
["SOMEURL","SOMEURL","SOMEURL","SOMEURL"]
```

Once you have your JSON data in this format, you can use the code you provided to read it into a Python list:

```
import json

fileObject = open("doc_1.json", "r")
jsonContent = fileObject.read()
aList = json.loads(jsonContent)
fileObject.close()  # Close the file when you're done with it

print(aList)
```

This code will read the JSON data from "doc_1.json" and convert it into a Python list. Make sure the JSON data in your file is without extra quotes and escape characters.

Comment: This is just useless ChatGPT crap. You already got at least two comments reminding you of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1. Please read it attentively, stop polluting the site, and delete your - well, its - answers. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use it, but ok i guess

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have double encoded json string:

```py
import json

with open("your_file.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

print(data, type(data))

data = json.loads(data)
print(data, type(data))  # data is of type `list`
```

Prints:

```py
["SOMEURL","SOMEURL","SOMEURL","SOMEURL"] <class 'str'>
['SOMEURL', 'SOMEURL', 'SOMEURL', 'SOMEURL'] <class 'list'>
```

---

Content of `your_file.json`:

```json
"[\"SOMEURL\",\"SOMEURL\",\"SOMEURL\",\"SOMEURL\"]"
```